# Telnet connection to servers frequently drops on battery

Tags: macos, terminal, network, server.app

This is a 15" 2018 MBP, i7 6-core 16gb RAM. I run multiple telnet connections to MUSHes through the terminal and also via website or desktop clients, however on battery power all the connections drop fairly frequently and simultaneously, despite no break in WiFi connection. On mains power the connections only drops if the WiFi connection goes down. It's been a problem since I bought the machine, and is a real headache. I understand telnet is deprecated and not included with current versions of OSX, but, AFAIK this is the only way to connect to MUSH servers and it's a major part of what I use a computer for. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I've also established that it's not a router problem by testing with Windows laptops, all able to maintain continuous connection on the same WiFi network, and the fact the Mac doesn't drop connection on mains power. I have tried all combinations of power saving settings with no difference.

Edit: This is on MacOS 10.15.7 but was on previous versions of MacOS as well, so I don't think it's related to an update.

Comment: Just out of curiosity...does it drop SSH connections when on battery as well?  I don't know of any "hook" `powerd` has with telnet where it will drop connections.

Comment: @Allan Hi! I haven't tested with SSH on battery. It's on mains power most of the time at my desk and have only used SSH on mains. Is there a way I can test SSH connections? I've only used SSH in circumscribed circumstances as part of an IT course.

Comment: Just go on battery when you make an SSH connection, leave it like you do the telnet and see if the connection drops.  It's just for diagnostics...to see if the behavior is consistent with other connections.

Comment: @Allan Ok as an update, I've got one  terminal window in SSH to localhost, and I've got another window telnetting to 8bit.fansi.org 4201. A friend in IT just told me to try disabling battery health management, and since I've done that (about thirty minutes ago) all connections stable. I'll wait and see.

Comment: Can you do it *with* health management enabled first?  Let's see what's going on before making changes.

Comment: @Allan  Can do! Will have to be tomorrow now as it's 3am. However since disabling batt health management and rebooting, all connections  have been stable for 1hr15m, and connections remained stable even after `sudo shutdown -s now` and left in sleep for 10 minutes. Tomorrow I will test with batt health enabled to properly resolve this.

Comment: That's good to know.

Comment: Extensive further testing, new network architecture, and with wireless adapter. Issue seems to be with battery health manager, so it is remaining disabled, but that is fine.